# How can i drag a moving image using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, draggable

Hello i am new to JQuery or java actually i am newbie at programming!!! I did basic tutorial of jQUERY and making a game using Jquery. I am stuck at one thing and also not sure if my code is correct anyway here is my code..

```js
var b = function($b, speed) {
    var beeWidth = $b.width();

    $b.animate({
        "right": "90%",
        "left": "90%"
    }, speed, function() {
        $b.animate({
            "left": 0 - beeWidth + "px"
        }, speed, function() {
            b($b, speed);
        });
    });

};
$(function() {
    b($("#b"), 5000);
    b($("#bOne"), 4500);
    b($("#bTwo"), 4000);
    b($("#bThree"), 3500);
    b($("#bfour"), 3000);
    b($("#bfive"), 2500);
    b($("#bsix"), 2000);
    b($("#bseven"), 1500);
});
```

```css
body * {
  display: block;
}
body {
    background-image: url("...");
}

img{
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-grid;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<img id="b" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/s/o/o/A/x/F/bee-md.png">
<img id="bOne" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/s/o/o/A/x/F/bee-md.png">
<img id="bTwo" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/s/o/o/A/x/F/bee-md.png">
<img id="bThree" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/s/o/o/A/x/F/bee-md.png">
<img id="bfour" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/s/o/o/A/x/F/bee-md.png">
<img id="bfive" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/s/o/o/A/x/F/bee-md.png">
<img id="bsix" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/s/o/o/A/x/F/bee-md.png">
<img id="bseven" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/s/o/o/A/x/F/bee-md.png">
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are trying to do, what you tried already and where are your problems?

Comment: Use this https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: Please explain how your game works and why you need drag image

Comment: Or this http://spritely.net/

Comment: Actually i was trying to make a game where the bee's are moving leftto right but each bee have a diffrent speed nd if u click on a bee u can drag it and put the bee in a cage(that i will make later) if u put em in a cage u will get pint but i am stuck atm.. Nd looks impossible to me idk its my first year in school in it nd i love coding nd wants to learn alot so trying to think a project and make it so i get used to with it nd have some experience thanks in advance 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can ! you should just use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) .

```js
$(function(){
  $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
});
```

```css
#draggable{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="draggable">
  I AM DRAGGABLE
</div>
```

Comment: Ik how to do that man but i want my pictures to drag nd they are moving i tried all ways to do that but noti dont know ;/ maybe i am putting my code on wrong place or something like if i wanna drag my first image i ca id #b but nothing happens.. Will be thankful for any kind of help thanks :)

Comment: @AliJockeY you can move any number of images and element if you add a draggable class to them ...

Comment: I already gave img a id nd cant i just call that id to drag it? Nd can u also tell me where to put my code in my script.js thanks :)